# spawning a rectangle inside of a bordered area

Tags: python, pygame

I am stuck on finding a way to get a random position in an area surrounded by walls. (Each side of the box has walls)
I want to spawn a food pellet in this box for the snake to go eat it, but I've tried multiple possibilites and I am just lost.

I started by subtracting the food size from the total width of the screen. I then subtracted the border with from that. And I figured that Im going to have to start the random process at the thickness of the the walls
So lets say the thickness of the walls is 30 (same size as the food pellet)
the random code I thought would be

```py
x = random.randint(wall_thickness, width-foodSize-wall_thickness)
```

But then I realized that id also have to round it to the nearest cell size.
But I get an error where the width-foodSize-wall_thickness is smaller than wall_thickness

```py
inGameX = world[0] - self.size #width
inGameY = world[1] - self.size #height

gapX = inGameX - wall_thickness
gapY = inGameY - wall_thickness
        
x = random.randint(wall_thickness, gapX/self.size) * self.size
y = random.randint(wall_thickness, gapY/self.size) * self.size

>>>

raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d, %d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (60, 18, -42)
```

This has ultimatley made me stuck and I dont know what to do

All of this is assuming that the wall thickness is a multiple of the food size but not the thickenss of the food.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of an idea to where you can loop through all the available spots by checking how far away you were from the walls via the wall_thickness

```py
available_spots = []
#loop through all the grid spaces on the x coords
for i in range(0, int(world[0]/self.size)):
    #loop through all the grid spaces on the y coords
    for j in range(0, int(world[1]/self.size)):
        # if i * a cell size is larger the wall thickness (if it is passed the wall)
        # if i * a cell size is smaller than the the wall on the other side
        # than youre inside the box now
        if i * self.size >= wall_thickness and i * self.size < world[0] - wall_thickness and j * self.size >= wall_thickness and j * self.size < world[1] - wall_thickness:
            # now check if any of the spots inside the box is part of the snake
            for node in snake.nodes:
                if node.x == i * self.size and node.y == j * self.size:
                    break
                    else:
                        # append it to the available spots
                        available_spots.append(vec2(i * self.size, j * self.size))

# pick from the available spots
self.pos = random.choice(availiable_spots)
```

Comment: Is this an answer or is it just an extension to the question?